# How can i debug this code correctly??? (problem in Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App"))

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, pdf

i have this code and i need to affect values for bookmarks pdf with access.
I have Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library installed and ticked
However when I execute the code I get the following error on the Set Aapp = CreatObject("AcroExch.App") line.

Run-time error '-2146959355 (80080005)': No such interface supported.

Anyone know what causes this and how to fix it please.

```
Private Sub Btn_Click()


    Dim bookmarks As Object
    Dim bookmark As Object
    
    ' Déclaration des variables
    Dim AcroApp As Object ' Objet Application Acrobat
    Dim AcroAVDoc As Object ' Objet Document Acrobat
    Dim AcroPDDoc As Object ' Objet Document PDF
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fichierPDF As String
    
    fichierPDF = "C:\Users\jhamchaoui\Desktop\print.pdf"
    
    ' Ouvrir le fichier PDF
    Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set AcroAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
    
    If AcroAVDoc.Open(fichierPDF, "") Then
        Set AcroPDDoc = AcroAVDoc.GetPDDoc
        
        ' Obtenir les signets
        Set bookmarks = AcroPDDoc.GetBookmarks
        For Each bookmark In bookmarks
            If bookmark.Title = "date" Then
                bookmark.SetValue "Jigo"
            ElseIf bookmark.Title = "serv" Then
                bookmark.SetValue "HAMC"
            End If
        Next bookmark
        
        ' Enregistrer les modifications dans le fichier PDF
        AcroPDDoc.Save 1, fichierPDF
        
        ' Fermer le document
        AcroPDDoc.Close
        
        ' Fermer le document AVDoc
        AcroAVDoc.Close 1
    End If

    ' Libérer les objets
    Set bookmarks = Nothing
    Set AcroPDDoc = Nothing
    Set AcroAVDoc = Nothing
    Set AcroApp = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have Adobe Acrobat Pro installed?

Comment: no i have Adobe Acrobat Reader DC

Comment: Won't work with just Reader, need Acrobat Pro.